Why `chrome.tabs.query(...)` is undefined in firefox?
Running the following code on the popup page of the firefox addon reports the error Uncaught TypeError: chrome.tabs.query(...) is undefined
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }).then 

But browser.tabs.query works fine, why is the behavior inconsistent between the two?

I would like to be able to just use the chrome namespace in firefox without the webextension-polyfill.

It doesn't return a Promise, because it's callback-based. See the documentation.
